# EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue

Tags: iphone

I am showing employee records as rows in a screen 
I want the option to remove these and show a new set of records when I click a button

The structure / organization of my code is as follows :
In My controller .h

```
NSMutableArray *employeeScrollViewArray;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *employeeScrollViewItems;
```

- Here I have a UIScrollView  - employeeScrollViewItems - which is populated with rows shown on the UI
- I also store these rows in an array - employeeScrollViewArray

Initialization and release of objects in MyController.m file is as shown:
In the method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
employeeScrollViewArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

I am releasing this mutable array in the method :

```
- (void)dealloc {
[employeeScrollViewArray release];
```

when the  view loads I populate this array with objects from a user Defined class in a method :
EmployeeDetail.m file

```
EmployeeDetail *empDetail=[[EmployeeDetail alloc]init];
empDetail.delegate=self;
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EmployeeDetail" owner:empDetail options:nil];
[self.employeeScrollViewItems addSubview:empDetail.view]; 
[employeeScrollViewArray addObject:empDetail];
```

The details of the "h" file foe EmployeeDetail.h is :

```
@interface EmployeeDetail : UIViewController


UIView *view;
```

This is the "view" that is populated with data and shown on the screen

I now want to cleanup /remove these objects 
So I tried things like this : ( which is then causing the exception )

```
int yyy = [employeeScrollViewArray count];
 for(int xxx=yyy-1;xxx>=0;xxx--){
    if ([[[employeeScrollViewItems subviews]objectAtIndex:xxx ]isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
     [[[employeeScrollViewItems subviews ]objectAtIndex:xxx] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [employeeScrollViewArray removeObjectAtIndex:xxx];
   }//for
```

This is the only way that I am able to remove these objects 
If I try to remove them separately I get this error

However even after I remove the items and code passes - it still throws this error 
If I remove this code then things work - but then I cannot remove these objects

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the error is coming from, but I have some general advice:

You should release the object after adding it to the array.

```
[employeeScrollViewArray addObject:empDetail];
[empDetail release];
```

The array's entries will be retained by the array itself. In the cleanup method (`dealloc`) now just release the array: `[employeeScrollViewArray release]`. That will also release all contained objects.

Mostly it is not necessary to cleanup the view hierachy. However, if you want to remove all subviews of `employeeScrollViewItems`, I'd do this:

```
for (UIView* subview in [employeeScrollViewItems subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: thanks phix - I forgot to state that yes I am releasing the object after adding to the array - the strange thing is that I think somehow the "view" within the "EmployeeDetail" object is interfering with the actual "EmployeeDetail" object

Comment: OK I ran it using NSZombie and this is what I get - "An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object(zombie) at address : 0x74aa4b0 and resposible caller is shown as " -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:]